# Не получается настроить fail2ban на Proxmox 8.1

Tags: proxmox

Создаю базовые настройки, пытаюсь проверить командой fail2ban-client -v status sshd и fail2ban-regex /var/log/daemon.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/proxmox.conf, но везде вылезает ошибка:

```
 ``fail2ban-client -v status sshd`
2024-02-22 08:14:01,752 fail2ban.configreader   [570371]: INFO    Loading configs for fail2ban under /etc/fail2ban 
2024-02-22 08:14:01,753 fail2ban.configparserinc[570371]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
2024-02-22 08:14:01,753 fail2ban.configparserinc[570371]: INFO      Loading files: ['/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf']
2024-02-22 08:14:01,753 fail2ban                [570371]: INFO    Using socket file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock
2024-02-22 08:14:01,753 fail2ban                [570371]: INFO    Using pid file /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid, [INFO] logging to /var/log/fail2ban.log
2024-02-22 08:14:01,754 fail2ban                [570371]: ERROR   Failed to access socket path: /var/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.sock. Is fail2ban running?`
```

При попытке запустить и проверить вылезает следующее:

```
`/etc/init.d/fail2ban start
Starting fail2ban (via systemctl): fail2ban.service.
root@prox:~# /etc/init.d/fail2ban status
× fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/fail2ban.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-02-22 08:19:40 +04; 3s ago
   Duration: 111ms
       Docs: man:fail2ban(1)
    Process: 571151 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
   Main PID: 571151 (code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION)
        CPU: 109ms

Feb 22 08:19:40 prox systemd[1]: Started fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service.
Feb 22 08:19:40 prox fail2ban-server[571151]: 2024-02-22 08:19:40,630 fail2ban.configreader   [571151]: WARNING 'allowipv6' not defined in 'Defin…one: 'auto'
Feb 22 08:19:40 prox fail2ban-server[571151]: 2024-02-22 08:19:40,643 fail2ban                [571151]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: Have…r sshd jail
Feb 22 08:19:40 prox fail2ban-server[571151]: 2024-02-22 08:19:40,647 fail2ban                [571151]: ERROR   Async configuration of server failed
Feb 22 08:19:40 prox systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=255/EXCEPTION
Feb 22 08:19:40 prox systemd[1]: fail2ban.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
    Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.`
```